# Facebook App Used on Sites

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook app. This app is a "Website with Facebook Login". However, I need to use it across several URLs. One for development, one for testing, and one for production. My urls looks like this:

```
Dev - http://localhost:[dynamicPortNumber]
Test - http://mysite.azurewebsites.net
Prod - http://www.mysite.com
```

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to allow multiple URLs to be associated with this app so that I can do end-to-end testing. Can someone please explain to me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using multiple top-level domains, the only way to handle this would be to create new App IDs for each instance (dev / test / prod).

However, if you have the freedom, using multiple subdomains in the same top-level domain will get you the result you are looking for. For example:

- Dev: dev.mysite.com
- Test: test.mysite.com
- Prod: www.mysite.com

This will allow you to use the same Facebook App ID across all domains, as long as you use "mysite.com" as the App Domain.

Don't forget to add your site's URL in the "Site URL" box in the "website with facebook login" section!

NOTE: I have, in the past, had to add each individual subdomain in the app domain box in an app for it to function properly, but usually it's because I've made an error somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is no way to deal with the issue of different URLs for development, testing and production using a single Facebook App ID, you will have to create 3 different App IDs for each of the cases and use them at different places. 
You can also check out [Getting Started with Your Facebook App on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook#working-locally) that does the same.